# ReactJS dynamic pages from mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

It's third day of research and I can't find simple solution. The thing is that I want to create dynamic reactjs page. For example "example.com/project/10" generates 10th project from mongodb. It seems pretty simple, however I don't know why it is so complicated to achieve using react.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using React Router -

```
<Route path='project/:project_id' component={Project} />

class Project extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount () {
    const { project_id } = this.props.match.params;
    fetch_project_from_db(project_id);
  }
  ...
}
```